# Tally a Dictionary Value For Key Object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I guess I'm tired today.  I can't come up with the correct way to tally a number object in a for loop used to build a PDF report.  I need to keep a running total (+=) on this object and put it at the bottom of the report.  here is where I'm referring to it for the PDF context. (inside a for loop).  A dictionary was created from a fetched array.

```
myNewString = [decimalFormatter stringFromNumber:[resultsDict valueForKey:@"dispatchMTMiles"]];
[myNewString drawInRect:CGRectMake(525, currentPageY, 40, 15) withFont:loadLineFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

I need to keep a running total of the dispatchMTMiles which in core data is a Integer16 type.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd add each one into a mutable array as you go, then just grab the array count.

Comment: I ended up doing an @"sum:" fetch before going into the PDF creation method.  I'm testing to insure the sum fetch is guaranteed to equal the pdf's fetched numbers with identical predicates and once manually added but I don't see how they could ever be different.  But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, and you have an array of dictionaries with @"dispatchMTMiles" key, then you can easily sum them up with key coding function, example:

```
NSArray *a = @[@{@"x": @1}, @{@"x": @2}, @{@"x": @3}];
NSNumber *sum = [a valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.x"]; // 6
```